# pull push atomic operation?

Tags: mongodb, atomic

I have a document with 2 arrays, I want to move one element from one array to the other, I tried this on the console and it works:

```
db.examplecol.update({_id: ObjectId("5056b4b2b9f53a21385076c5")} , {'$pull':{setA:3}, '$push':   {setB:3}})
```

But I haven't seen yet an example of 2 updates in a single command. My question is if this is an atomic operation? If something goes wrong in the middle of this operation, do I have the risk of "losing" my element by it have been pulled but not pushed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on [MongoDB's Atomic Operations](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Atomic+Operations) documentation and since your operation is on a single document, then the operation should be atomic.  You should ensure that you're using journalling, so if the power is pulled half-way through your update, then MongoDB will recover to a known, good state prior to the update.

Comment: I just wasnt sure cause I see sometimes people calling 2 operations, like the "replace the member Matt Sorum with Steven Adler" in http://www.hacksparrow.com/mongoskin-tutorial-with-examples.html